# On typing/entering data in text box getting the entered value to display

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a text box, after entering which i need to get that value and display in alert box,without using any forms or buttons.

This is what I used: But its not working ,it gives null value on loading of the file.

**HTML**

```
<tr>
    <td><br>Address of Patient</td>
    <td> <br> <input type="text" name="inc_patientAddress" id="inc_address" required></td>
</tr>
```

**Jvascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var x = document.getElementById('inc_address');
alert(x.value);
</script>
```

I want to display the text box value after entering the data in text box , Is it possible? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `blur` event:

```
document.getElementById('inc_address').addEventListener('blur', function() {
    console.log(this.value);
}, false);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/hop3szu4/

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: Thank you :) Its working fine  , One more doubt, Can v get the text box entered value in php?

Comment: For that you have to use `xmlHttpRequest/ajax`

Comment: can we get it without submit button by using ajax/xmlhttprequest?

Comment: @LillyShk Yes, that's what `AJAX` is

Comment: @LillyShk http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp might help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80732/discussion-between-lilly-shk-and-tushar).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

For every input

```
$('#inc_address').on('input', function() {
alert($(this).val());
});
```

[Working Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hop3szu4/2/)

For every complete Input

```
$('#inc_address').on('change', function() {
alert($(this).val());
});
```

[Working Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hop3szu4/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add blur function for that input.
As soon as it will lost focus from that text box it will call this function and so the alert will be displayed.

```
<input type="text" name="inc_patientAddress" id="inc_address" onblur="myFunction()" required>
```

Call this funtion on blur:

```
myFunction(){
      alert("#inc_address").value();
}
```

Comment: Question is not tagged with `jQuery` and not even mentioned that uses `jQuery`